# Add pivot-table to a google spreadsheet, via the API

Tags: google-api, pivot-table, google-docs-api, google-docs

I'd like to automatically create one of these pivot tables:

https://drive.googleblog.com/2011/05/summarize-your-data-with-pivot-tables.html

Given some data and parameters, the script would create a new google spreadsheet, complete with pivot-table and chart, non-interactively.

Is this possible?

Comment: So, have you found the answer? Is it possible to create a pivot chart via API?

Comment: @Sergei: As you can see, this question has no answers.

Comment: I guess the best way to solve the problem is to prepare a google spreadsheet "template" with some data and pivot chart and change the data itself via API, so the pivot chart would be recalculated automatically

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is a [partial answer](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/pivot-charts-library).  I haven't tried it yet, and I wouldn't swear by it till I do. If anyone does try this technique, post here.